# Connecting a Microsoft SQL Server database to my Java project

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am having difficulty linking up my Microsoft SQL Server database table to my java project, having successfully designed my project.

Whenever I run my connection, the project frame successfully loads but the database gets disrupted as I'm notified *No suitable driver found* for my database.

I have added my sqljdbc4 driver to the library of the project, it's still coming up with such alert.

Here is my connection code:

```
public void doConnect(){
         try{
         String un = "casey";
        String pw = "****";
        String host = "jdbc:sqlserver://caseydido\\mssqlexpress:1433;databaseName=stock";

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM STAFF_DATA";
        //loading the driver class
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); //This is for driver sqljdbc2*
//        Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"); /*This is for driver sqljdbc4*/
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(un, pw, host);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            conn.close();
        }
```

NOTE casey is the username of the database table, the name of the database is STOCK,  **** represents my password.

I also tried adding the sqljdbc4 driver path to my system environmental variable path, it still did not work.

Comment: You may want to double-check the signature for `DriverManager.getConnection()` in the manual.

Comment: To be more specific: the signature is [`DriverManager.  getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) in other words: you are calling it with the arguments in the wrong order. Something, BTW, which should have been immediately apparent had you actually read the entire exception message.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `Class.forName()` is no longer needed.

Comment: kindly make the correction where necessary if you can, so I can effect it and proceed with my work please.

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

You need to correct the following code, as mentioned by Mark Rotteveel. Also, consider using meaningful names for your variables so that you understand what goes where.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(un, pw, host);
```

To the following:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, un, pw);
```

You need to add the `SQLJDBC` connector jar in your project's build path (if you are using an IDE as like ECLIPSE) and also consider adding the path to the connector jar to environmental variable `CLASSPATH`

Please follow the MSDN Documentation to use the right syntax to construct the host URL. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url).

**EDIT-1:**

As per your code, the connection is supposed to be closed because of a mistake that you've made. You need to change this from:

```
while (rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    conn.close();
}
```

To the following, to solve your problem!

```
while (rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
conn.close();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response N00b programmer. I understand my variables names. I have added the sqljdbc4 to my project library. As for the connection(host, un, pw), I tried it, it was showing error. that solved, but now it's showing the CONNECTION IS CLOSED....meanwhile, my project successfully opens

Comment: @CaseyRunor, Edited my answer as per the latest comment from OP